# colly golang save local copy

Tags: go, go-colly

I'm writing Scraping in Golang and wanted to implement this logic, first I save HTML copy on my computer and then I process this copy, after reading the documentation I found the method response.Save, but in the end it saves the result of the work. Can anyone tell me how to do it correctly?

````
    package main
  
    import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    )
    
    func main() {
        GetPage := colly.NewCollector()
        GetPage.Clone()
        GetPage.OnHTML("a[href]", func(htmlElement *colly.HTMLElement) {
            link := htmlElement.Attr("href")
            fmt.Printf("Link: %q -> %s/n", htmlElement.Text, link)
            GetPage.Visit(htmlElement.Request.AbsoluteURL(link))
        })
        GetPage.OnRequest(func(request *colly.Request) {
            fmt.Println("Visiting", request.URL.String())
        })
        GetPage.OnResponse(func(response *colly.Response) {
            response.Save("1.html")
        })
        GetPage.Clone()
        GetPage.Visit("https://mail.com") ```
````

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please clarify what you have done, and what you want separately, as it is really unclear in the current form.

Comment: I want to download a page from mail.com to my computer in html format using colly golang, then I want to take links and pictures from it and then put it into the database.

Comment: «I want to download a page from mail.com to my computer in html format»–but your statement «in the end it saves the result of the work» sounds like the Save method does exactly what you're after. If not, what is that "result of the work" then?

Comment: I mean that the file does not contain the whole html copy from the site, but only parts of it, my task is to download the full copy of the page and then process it.

Comment: I want to get the functionality similar to the browser file---> save as ----> file.html

Comment: What do you mean you get only parts of it ? Some sites render themselves dynamically using javascript, so normal scraping tools which do not run javascript will get a different looking HTML. Is that your problem ?

Comment: Part of it is not a full copy of the page of the site, in principle, I have already solved the problem thank you for your help.